# Guided ticket handeling in Jira?

Tags: jira, ticket-system

I wonder if it's possible to specify ticket "types" in Jira and have specific data that MUST be filed in for a given ticket type. Say we have a "campaign start" ticket type. In that the creator must set a few dates, attach a file with some data etc. And also have a default cost in time for a given ticket type so that an estimated date when it could be started and done could be shown. Is this possible?

Edit: By `And also have a default cost in time for a given ticket type so that an estimated date when it could be started and done could be shown.` I mean if it would be possible to set that a 'campaign start' type of standard ticket would require 3 days of work to get done. So that if we let a specific few people create tickets they could see like a time-line of when their ticket could be started on and when it could be assumed to be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - there is quite a bit possible with JIRA, including enforcing fields at certain stages and so on / so forth.  This is all well documented on the Atlassian site, or you can work with one of their partners (like us :-) ...) for setting up your project configuration.

Enforcing certain fields can be done through the field configuration scheme or through the use of specific plugins.

Could you elaborate on

> And also have a default cost in time
>   for a given ticket type so that an
>   estimated date when it could be
>   started and done could be shown. Is
>   this possible?"

Francis

Answer (score 0):

The specific documentation is on [Field Configuration Schemes](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Associating+Field+Behaviour+with+Issue+Types). The default cost in time sounds like setting a default value for the system Original Estimate field, which it would be nice if you could also do via the Field Configuration Scheme, but you currently can't. I'd look at some injected javascript to set a default, perhaps using the Behaviours plugin.